# How to redirect a page in Next.js for static export

Tags: redirect, next.js, static, server-side-rendering

**Background:**
I have a **tag** page in my content based website that shows links to the pages that their content is tagged with the tag. But it turns out that my tagging system had a problem and now I want to prune the pages. So I need to redirect tags that only have one post in them to the single post. The following is what I tried so far:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context: any) {

  const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/post/?tag=${context.params.tag}`)
  const posts = await res.json()

  for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    posts[i].link = '/blog/post/' + posts[i].slug;
  }
 
  if (posts.length===1){
    return {redirect: {
      permanent: true,
      destination: posts[0].link,
    },
  }
  }
  return {
    props: {
      posts: posts,
    },
  }
}
```

**The Problem:**
The solution works when I run next locally. But it fails when I want to export the project to static.

So what is the appropriate way of redirecting for the current situation that works in static mode.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with redirects in Next.js for static exports, you should use the redirects configuration in the `next.config.js` file. Unfortunately, you cannot use getStaticProps for redirects in a static export because it only runs at `build time`, and redirects need to work at `runtime`.

Here's how you can set up redirects for your situation:

In your `next.config.js` file, you can define the redirects using the redirects property. For your specific use case, you want to redirect tags that have only one post to a single post. Here's an example:

```js
// next.config.js file
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/tags`); // Fetch a list of tags or your data source
    const tags = await res.json();

    const redirects = [];

    tags.forEach((tag) => {
      if (tag.posts.length === 1) {
        redirects.push({
          source: `/tags/${tag.slug}`,
          destination: `/blog/post/${tag.posts[0].slug}`, // Redirect to the single post
          permanent: true, // Use permanent redirects if appropriate
        });
      }
    });

    return redirects;
  },
};
```

Comment: Redirects are not working with "export" at all :(

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-no-custom-routes

Comment: Yep that is right :(